# Java equivalent of C#'s 'Enumerable.Any'

Tags: java, if-statement, string-search

In C# there is a way of reducing the length of an if-statement by using `Enumerable.Any` to check if elements in a sequence satisfy a condition (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

For example Instead of:

```
If ( string.Contains(">") || string.Contains("<") || string.Contains("&") || string.Contains("l") || string.Contains("p") )
```

We can use

```
if (new [] { ">", "<", "&", "l", "p"}.Any(w => string.Contains(w)))
```

Is there an equivalent, if not better, way of doing this in Java?

Comment: Just for completeness: you can also use `.Any(string.Contains)` rather than the more verbose `.Any(w => string.Contains(w))` in C#.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With Java 8 you can write something like:

```
if (Stream.of(">", "<", "&", "l", "p").anyMatch(string::contains)) {
  ...
}
```

Out of curiosity I ran a benchmark to compare this method vs a regex. Code and results below (lower score = faster). Streams perform an order of magnitude better than regex.

```
Benchmark                                    (s)  Mode  Samples     Score    Error  Units
c.a.p.SO30940682.stream   >aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  avgt       10    49.942 ±  1.936  ns/op
c.a.p.SO30940682.stream   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>  avgt       10    54.263 ±  1.927  ns/op
c.a.p.SO30940682.stream   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaap  avgt       10   131.537 ±  4.908  ns/op
c.a.p.SO30940682.stream   paaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  avgt       10   129.528 ±  7.352  ns/op
c.a.p.SO30940682.regex    >aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  avgt       10   649.867 ± 27.142  ns/op
c.a.p.SO30940682.regex    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>  avgt       10  1047.122 ± 89.230  ns/op
c.a.p.SO30940682.regex    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaap  avgt       10  1029.710 ± 61.055  ns/op
c.a.p.SO30940682.regex    paaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  avgt       10   694.309 ± 32.675  ns/op
```

Code:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public class SO30940682 {

  @Param({">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>",
          "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaap", "paaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"}) String s;

  @Benchmark public boolean stream() {
    return Stream.of(">", "<", "&", "l", "p").anyMatch(s::contains);
  }

  @Benchmark public boolean regex() {
    return s.matches("^.*?(>|<|&|l|p).*$");
  }
}
```

Comment: @MarcoAcierno String::contains make reference to a static method, which does not exist. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: My bad, I removed the comment. I missed the fact that `string` is a variable

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I wonder if Regex would be faster for checking substrings instead of single characters. I'm not sure if `contains()` performs well in those cases.

Comment: Thank you. This is a perfect solution. Bruce Wayne's solution using regex can be useful if people are not working with JAVA 8.

Comment: If you really want speed and check for single characters only, you'll want to check all of the few chars in a single loop on all characters in the string. I wonder how much faster that is compared to the other methods...

Comment: Why you write this regex like this? Of course it is slow. It's one of the worst way to write this regex. Why you not simply write s.matches(">|<|&|l|p");?

Comment: @abc667 `String.matches` matches the entire string - so unless the string is only one character long your regex won't work. There may be other, better options though (for example compiling the Pattern and using `return pattern.matcher(string).find()` would probably be more efficient).

Comment: Oh, java :\. Sory, i forgot what that method does. But if you see two .* in regex it almost certain that this regex is wrong and will be horrible slow.

Answer (score 9):

With Java 8, this is possible with the [anyMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) method:

```
if (Stream.of(">", "<", "&", "l", "p").anyMatch(w -> string.contains(w))) {

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Looks like [`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsAny()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) does what you want.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have Java 8, you could just use a regular expression to accomplish your task.

`string.matches("^.*?(<|>|p|1|&).*$")` should do the trick.

**EDIT:**

I wonder which solution performs faster. Eventhough JIT can inline all the lambda goodiness, `Stream`(s) might be slower than using a regular expression. I could be completely wrong and I'd appreciate any insight into this from Java 8 stalwarts.